# Function to find last row, but procedure ignoring the first row as written

Tags: vb.net, excel

I wrote the following function to find the last row of any column:

```
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal rngToCheck As Excel.Range) As Long
    Dim rngLast As Excel.Range
    rngLast = rngToCheck.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious)
    If rngLast Is Nothing Then
        GetLastRow = rngToCheck.Rows.Count
    Else
        GetLastRow = rngLast.Rows.Count
    End If
End Function
```

I use this function anytime I am dealing with a dynamic range, which is several times on my project. Now, I want to find the last row on column F, but starting on F2. It has to ignore row F1 because that is the heading. However, it is not and I get an error that it cannot convert from String to Double, which is expected because F1 is a string (Column Title) and everything else is data.

I do not want to change my function because in some instances I will need to go from row 1 down and sometimes from row 2 down, which is what I thought I did on my code below, but it does not work, it keeps reading F1 and of course errors out because F1 is a string and the rest of the column is Double.

```
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
Dim xlWSEmployee As Excel.Worksheet = CType(CType(xlWB.Sheets("byEmployee"), Excel.Worksheet), Excel.Worksheet)
Dim xlWSPosition As Excel.Worksheet = CType(CType(xlWB.Sheets("byPosition"), Excel.Worksheet), Excel.Worksheet)

Sub renameColumns()
    With xlWSPosition
        Dim colValue As Excel.Range
        For Each colValue In .Range("F2:F" & GetLastRow(.Cells)) 'Change range as needed
            If colValue.Value > 0 Then
                'used offset instead of range,ie (E1:E)
                .Range(colValue.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value = "N"
            Else
                .Range(colValue.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value = "Y"
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: have you through about using the .End method of the Range object to get the last cell.  dim r as range    r.End(xlDown).Row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like to rely on `TryParse` too much, but this is the kind of situations where it does an excellent job:

```
For Each colValue In .Range("F2:F" & GetLastRow(.Cells)) 'Change range as needed
    Dim curVal As Integer
    If (colValue.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso Integer.TryParse(colValue.Value.ToString(), curVal)) Then
        If curVal > 0 Then
            'used offset instead of range,ie (E1:E)
            .Range(colValue.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value = "N"
        Else
            .Range(colValue.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value = "Y"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the cell value is numeric before you use it with the following:

```
If IsNumeric(colValue.Value) And colValue.Value > 0 Then
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is to use a for statement

```
Dim fColumn As Integer
fColumn = 6
For i = 2 To GetLastRow(.Cells)
    If Cells(i, fColumn).Value > 0 Then
        Cells(i, fColumn).Offset(0, -1).Value = "N"
    Else
        Cells(i, fColumn).Offset(0, -1).Value = "Y"
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: What is the difference between using for and foreach on this context? The OP is complaining about the given cell being a string and thus triggering an error when trying colVal.Value > 0. His loop is fine (I understand that he defined the ranges properly). Also why relying on Cells instead of on Range? (which, by the way, is wrongly defined -> this is not how you write VB.NET code). Your code does not solve the problem, but also delivers the same than the OP version (when properly written).

Comment: Here is the exerpt from the original post "It has to ignore row F1 because that is the heading. However, it is not and I get an error that it cannot convert from String to Double, which is expected because F1 is a string (Column Title) and everything else is data."  So after reading that we know that his issue is that it is doing this from the header cell hence the for loop as you can start the for loop on any row by assigning a value to 'i';  You can even change it to have the row passed in and assign it to 'i'.  Cells are a Range Object

Comment: (I know what Cells is; but just like this does not make anything in VB.NET other than triggering an error... in my code I am writing .Range because it is inside a With structure (omitted), but you have to write the dot). From the range definition in the original code, it is clear that the range is F2 to "last F" if the OP has problems to get the proper columns is because other part of the code, not of this. At least, now it is a bit clearer to me the point of your answer :)